# Шифрование данных с помощью массива

Tags: python, массивы

Олимпиада уже закончилась, но мне все равно интересно, как решить одну задачу.

1. После ввода данных необходимо удалить пробелы из строки и поместить её в массив.
2. Дальше нужно найти корень из числа, которое равно количеству символов в строке.
3. Ближайшее к корню меньшее целое число будет являться количеством строк (каждая строка - символ), а большее ближайшее к корню целое число будет количеством столбцов в двумерном массиве.
4. После этого, нужно транспонировать матрицу и вывести построчно

**Пример:**

Исходная матрица:

```
[ [a] [b] [c] ]
[ [d] [e] [f] ]
[ [g] [h] [x] ]
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

`adg beh cfx`

PS. Вот что получилось

```
import math
lines = input("Веддите даные для шифрования :")

w_massive = list(lines)

for i in w_massive:
    if i == ' ':
        w_massive.remove(i)  #Убираю пробелы

strings = len(w_massive) 


strings = math.sqrt(strings) #Корень с длины и округление к большему
strings = math.ceil(strings) 

massive = list()  #Тут должен быть ответ

for i in range(len(w_massive)):
    
    massive.append(w_massive[i])
    pass
    #Дальше не знаю как, должен как-то получится цикл внутри цикла

    введите сюда код
```

Comment: ну так ваш код где?

Comment: Для строки длиной 8 символов расчёт размера матрицы не работает. Получается размер 2 х 3 ! Это всего 6 символов и 8 туда никак не запихнуть.

Comment: Ошибся, получается кол-во строк равно кол-ву столбцов. Дальше то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое нужно:

```
import math


def solve(s):
    s = ''.join(s.split())
    cols = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(s)))
    return ' '.join([s[i::cols] for i in range(cols)])


print(solve('a b c d e  f   g h       x    '))  # adg beh cfx
print(solve('a b c d e f g h i j'))             # aei bfj cg dh
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то меня интересует последняя строка.Что она делает?

Comment: 4 пункт задания, только я не создавал матрицу, а работал со строкой. Пробегаем по элементам с определенным шагом